# what is the most convenient way to use dialogs in non-gui app?

Tags: python, windows, user-interface

I'm programming an excel-add on and I don't need main windows and all the shiny widgets/toolkits, but I need dialogs.

here's my attempt at creating one(using pywin32):

```
import win32ui, win32con

def openFileDialog(extensions = None, multi = False):
    """open a Windows File 'Open' Dialog. returns a list of path of files selected by user.

    Keyword arguments:
    extensions (default None) - a list or tuple containing (description, ext) 
    pair of acceptable files.
      ext can be a string - i.e) '*.txt', or a list or tuple of many strings ['*.txt', '*.htm']
      description is a string describing corresponding ext. 

    multi - (default False) True to allow user to select more than one files. 
    """

    openFlags = win32con.OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT|win32con.OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST
    if multi:
        openFlags|=win32con.OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT

    dlg = win32ui.CreateFileDialog(1,
                                   None,
                                   None,
                                   openFlags,
                                   extensionFilterString(extensions))

    if dlg.DoModal()!=win32con.IDOK:
        return None

    return dlg.GetPathNames()
```

although they work, I think that is really un-pythonic. I had a look at pyside and they have `QFileDialog` - but it requires `QApplication` and seems like that `Qapplication` takes over the main loop. I don't think I need all the hassle and I really don't know about python gui programming. What is the most convenient way to open file dialogs in python?

Comment: You could write the GUI code in excel and call several C functions from it

Comment: doesnt VB in excell offer dialogs?

Comment: For this sort of thing, try [EasyGUI](http://easygui.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Glad to hear you found it useful. Although the the latest version has a few design quirks (which can be changed since it comes with source), overall I think it's well executed and gets the job done.

Comment: @martineau yeah, I examined their source and I'll write some my custom dialog-showing functions based on their one.